# Reloading data with chart.dataSource.reloadFrequency adds the data to the chart in stead of replacing it

Tags: amcharts

I've added this code

```
chart.dataSource.reloadFrequency = 60000;
```

to live reload the chart data.
It works, the network tab is showing that, and the data is loaded, but it looks like it's *added* and not *replaced*.
[image]

The docs say:
In case your data changes dynamically, you might want to set up the data loader to reload the data at preset intervals, so that your chart is always up-to-date.
To do that, use dataSource.reloadFrequency setting.
It's a number of milliseconds you want your chart data to be reloaded at.
For example if I want my chart to reload its data every 5 seconds, i'll set this to 5000:

Comment: Do you have `incremental` set to true? That would explain why it's adding instead of replacing as the default behavior is to replace the data on reload (i.e. `incremental = false`). If that's not the case, please post a fiddle.

Comment: No, I did not set incremental to true. Accoding tot the docs "This will instruct the loader to treat each new load of data as addition to the old data". This created a chart with multiple datalines

Comment: Please post your chart setup, then. I can't reproduce this locally.

Comment: it's a little bit of complex setup, with data coming from my server

Comment: Surely you can pare it down to a minimal version of your chart config, without your data, that is enough to reproduce the problem? Without seeing what you have, it's very hard to say what's wrong, especially if you're using the latest release. As it stands, reloadFrequency behaves correclty on all of our examples.

Comment: Can I DM you my live code?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and changing these line to false helped:

```
chart.dataSource.incremental = false;
```